# Retrieve value from an HTML drop down into a Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am attempting to retrieve the results of my two drop down bars on my `validation1.html` script so I can determine if they have made a selection yet or not, giving a result of true or false. I am having a tough time as I don't have much experience with javascript, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function validate1() {
  valCheck3 = true;
  var resultSelect = SelectCheck(document.forms["contact information"] ["gender"].value);
  var image3 = getImage(true, "gender");
  var labelGender = getNotification3(Boolean(resultSelect), "gender");
  document.getElementById("Gender").appendChild(image3);
  document.getElementById("Gender").appendChild(labelGender);
}
```

(This is only a snippet of code but,) but so far it seems to not be giving out any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you

https://jsfiddle.net/af5nhx91/

```
<select id="testytest" name="testytest">
        <option value ='option one'> option one </option>
        <option value = 'option two'> option two </option>
</select>
```

```
var value = document.getElementById('testytest').value;
```

Comment: Awesome that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use .value function as this

```
var e = document.getElementById("dropdownID");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Assuming *e* is a reference to a select element, `e.value` is less to type. ;-)